# Error message when creating R package using the dynlm function

Tags: r, r-package

I am trying to create an R package which includes a function which requires the dynlm R package to use the function dynlm as in the following sample code,

```
#' Title
#'
#' @param x A numeric database.
#'
#' @return
#' @export
#' @import dynlm
#' @examples
#' M1Germany <- dynlm::M1Germany
#' M1Germany <- as.data.frame(M1Germany)
#' estimat <- equations(M1Germany)
#' estimat
equations <- function (x) {
eq <- dynlm::dynlm(loggnp ~ L(interest,1) + logprice, data = x)
 return(summary(eq))
}
```

I built the DESCRIPTION file as follow

```
Package: fundyn
Type: Package
Title: What the Package Does (Title Case)
Version: 0.1.0
Author: Myself Myself
Maintainer: The package maintainer <yourself@somewhere.net>
Description: More about what it does (maybe more than one line)
    Use four spaces when indenting paragraphs within the Description.
License: GPL-3
Encoding: UTF-8
LazyData: true
Imports: 
car,
dynlm,
lmtest,
stats,
zoo
RoxygenNote: 7.1.2
```

This is just a sample to replicate the problem in the function that I am building. When running the Check under the Build tab, I get the following error message in both, my original function and in the example that I just presented,

Error in merge.zoo(loggnp, L(interest, 1), logprice, retclass = "list",  :
could not find function "merge.zoo"

I took a look at the dynlm pdf documentation and it says

Depends R (>= 2.10.0), zoo

Imports stats, car (>= 2.0-0), lmtest

My original function uses various other packages and there is no problem with them. I noticed that none of these packages have "Depends". They only have "Imports". So, I suspect that the problem is because the package dynlm "Depends" on zoo and I have been unable to correctly incorporate zoo into my package.

What is the problem here?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: If you look at the bottom of the CRAN page for dynlm there are multiple other packages that use it so it is more likely that the problem is on your end. Look at how those packages use Depends and Imports. https://cran.r-project.org/package=dynlm

Comment: Dear Sir, very much thank you for your reply. I acknowledge that I am new to package development. Do you mean the packages under "Reverse dependencies:"? As far as I know, these packages are packages that need dynlm to work. On the other hand, I added to my package all the packages under "Imports" of the package dynlm and I am still getting the same error message. My guess the problem is in how the package "zoo" is imported into my package.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error message in another context. Resolved it with simple

> `library(zoo)`

before running the dependent function. I don't know how useful it will be in your case, when trying to build a package, though.